# Cloudformation error: Value of property NetworkInterfaces must be a list of objects

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I get the error `Value of property NetworkInterfaces must be a list of objects` when referring to a NetworkInterface in a CloudFormation template.

Here is the relevant section:

`MyAppNetworkInterface:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetPrivate`

MyApp:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      InstanceType: t2.medium
      NetworkInterfaces:
        - !Ref MyAppNetworkInterface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it that way.  Instead , create the two resources independently, then connect with a network interface attachment resource.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-network-interface-attachment.html

Answer (score 4):

You can actually refer the Network Interface directly from the EC2 Host. But the syntax is slightly different:

```
MyAppNetworkInterface:
  Type: AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface
  Properties:
    SubnetId: !Ref SubnetPrivate

MyApp:
  Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
  Properties:
    InstanceType: t2.medium
    NetworkInterfaces:
    - NetworkInterfaceId: !Ref MyAppNetworkInterface
      DeviceIndex: 0
```

(see: http://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-network-interface.html#cfn-awsec2networkinterface-templateexamples)